# text alignment on a picker xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

i am having trouble with aligning the text on an expanded picker to the centre and i would have thought it would be something like this...

[image]

and here is the picker on the emulator...

[image]

How would i get that SIZE text to sit in the middle but keep the line expanded also can it be done through the xaml code instead of c# code

cheers.

Comment: Image of code are annoying, just saying.

Comment: FYI, `HorizontalOptions` is not text alignment, but it is specific how your picker going to located horizontally

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE***

Actually is very easy:

```
<Picker Title="Selecione o bairro" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

...OLD

You need to use a `CustomRenderer` for this.

**ANDROID**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BetterPicker), typeof(BetterPickerRenderer))]

namespace MDWS.Droid
{
    public class BetterPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BetterPicker), typeof(BetterPickerRenderer))]

namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class BetterPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works but it displays picker as a scrollable picker. For example if there are 5 items total then only 3 are visible and you need to scroll it. How to set aligment but preserve all the items visible?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you will have to implement a `CustomRenderer` for this.
 
For each platform `OnElementChanged` you will have to set the alignment for `Picker`'s title.

Luckily this topic is very nicely explained in [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

P.S.: Welcome to stackoverflow.com, please take a moment to read this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1970317) which nicely explains why posting a screenshot of code is a bad practice.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same issue and noticed that if you set up the android renderer using the "using"

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
```

It retains the original styling

Answer (score -2):

Can You try LayoutOptions.Center

Otherwise we need custom renderer for this.